# How to address entity that uses composite identity key in OData Url?

Tags: url, entity, odata, asp.net-web-api, composite-primary-key

I have an *entity OrderItem* that has *OrderId* and *ProductId* integer fields and these two fields form the *identity key/primary key* for this table.
I would like to use *OData/Web API* to expose such entities through a service and to be able to select *OrderItem* instances by they **composite ID**.

What should be the format of the **URL**?

Are there any best practices for handling such scenarios?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Composite keys in the URL use syntax like this:

```
~/OrderItems(OrderId=1234,ProductId=1234)
```

The "grammar" is defined in the [OData ABNF Construction Rules](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) (see the definition for "compoundKey")

An example usage can be found in OASIS' [OData Version 4.0. Part 2: URL Conventions Plus Errata 03](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752343)

Note that the "composite key" (aka "complex key predicate") has been around [since OData 1.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#AddressingEntries).

Answer (score 12):

First, you have to make sure that you explicitly mention that it has a composite key, in configuration file

```
builder.EntityType<OrderItem>().HasKey(t => new { t.OrderId, t.ProductId});
```

Then, the action should have the following header

```
public SingleResult<OrderItem> Get([FromODataUri] string keyOrderId, [FromODataUri] string keyProductId)
```

Please note the prefix(**key**) used for both parameters!

This is OData V4. Please also refer to https://odata.github.io/WebApi/13-06-KeyValueBinding/

Comment: You're answer appears to be more of a comment, and the original question does not involve Entity Framework, so your comment might not be applicable.