# Support OData for an entity with 2 composite keys in ASPNetBoilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate framework for ASP.NET Core. How do I add a OData controller to support an entity with 2 composite keys.

I have the composite key defined as:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<vFamilyItem>().HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.FamilyId });
```

I have my get function defined as follows:

```
        public SingleResult<vFamilyItem> Get([FromODataUri] int keyId, [FromODataUri] int keyFamilyId)
    {
        CheckGetPermission();

        var entity = Repository.GetAll().Where(e => e.Id.Equals(keyId) && e.FamilyId.Equals(keyFamilyId));

        return SingleResult.Create(entity);
    }
```

but get a 404 error when calling http://localhost:21021/odata/vFamilyItems(Id=77623,FamilyId=2648)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to address entity that uses composite identity key in OData Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253205/8601760)

Comment: Thanks aaron, I've ensured I've got the composite key defined and ensured I've got the key prefix in place for the parameters. But get a 404 error trying to access it?

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata/tree/master/AbpODataDemo-Core](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata/tree/master/AbpODataDemo-Core)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the order of the 2 keys in your API call.

From what I can tell, the key names and values need to be alphabetical in your call:

`http://localhost:21021/odata/vFamilyItems(FamilyId=2648,Id=77623)`

It doesn't seem to matter what order they are in the model, the FluentAPI defining its key nor even the C# function signature.

The way I figured out I had my 2 the wrong way around compared to expected was to hit the end point:
`http://localhost:21021/$odata`

which requires the UseODataRouteDebug() call in startup.cs:

```c#
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
app.UseODataRouteDebug();
...
}
```